# Trying to Generate Dependencies Report with Maven

Tags: java, maven

im working with Maven and Im trying to generate an OWASP dependencies report. My POM is the following:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>P2LyH</groupId>
    <artifactId>P2_LH</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                        <report>checkstyle</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
                <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
                <version>6.0.3</version>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <report>aggregate</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.13.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <!-- Plugin de Sonar para ejecutar sonarqube-->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.0.1746</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- Plugin para generar el site-->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.9.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0.1746</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>sonar</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <!-- Optional URL to server. Default value is http://localhost:9000 -->
                <sonar.host.url>
                    http://localhost:9000
                </sonar.host.url>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

The POM is alright as far as I have checked it right before adding the dependency-check. The rest of the code basically generates other reports that I will use to look for some security errors.
When I tried to generate the report by mvn site, it gave me the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.9.0:site (default-site) on project P2_LH: Error generating dependency-check-maven:6.0.3:aggregate report
```

Why is this error happening?

Comment: If you run it with `-X`, what error do you get?

Comment: DatabaseException: Unable to connect to the database - if this error persists it may be due to a corrupt database. Consider running `purge` to delete the existing database
                caused by DatabaseException: Unable to connect to the database
                caused by JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: File corrupted while reading record: null. Possible solution: use the recovery tool [90030-199]
                caused by IllegalStateException: File corrupted in chunk 111, expected page length 4..1536, got 285344943 [1.4.199/6]

Comment: Maybe you need to erase your local repository and try again.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: The local repository is usually positioned in the your user directory below `.m2/repository`. Delete (or rename) this directory.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try to replace OWASP plugin to the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
    <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.1</version>
  </plugin>
```

And after that please try to run the following command:

> mvn test org.owasp:dependency-check-maven:check

HTML report should be generated

Comment: Same result as the other one.

Comment: Can you please try to add owasp plugin to <build> instead <reporting> ?

Comment: If I do that, it works, but It doesn´t generate anything.